# NSWindow's title as indicator popup button

Tags: macos, cocoa, popup, indicator, nstoolbar

I'm trying to make my first Cocoa app (previously I was making iOS apps) and what I wish to do for my custom view is make it's title clickable with indicator (accessory) triangle facing down.
Clicking the title would open a popup/menu with my items.

How is that doneable in Cocoa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rdelmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872015/307881) is probably the easiest way to go, but may not do exactly what you might want to do (which is replace the actual title with a pop up item, instead of having a popup button under the title in the toolbar area). With respect to functionality your application  will probably work just as well using the toolbar.

If, however, you truly want to replace the actual title, the means of going about this would be to set the `NSWindow` title text to `@""` to hide it, and redraw it by sticking in your own view.

```
[[[theWindow contentView] superview] addSubview:theSubview];
```

This basically tells the superview of the main content view to add another subview (direct "translation" from the code), and you'll have to tinker with the frame of this new subview to have it be positioned where the title should be positioned (as now it's free to be placed anywhere in the window frame, including *on top of the title bar*, as opposed to simply inside the content view).

`theSubview` can be your popup button, or whatever you want, and you'll also probably have to custom draw the popup button to match the original drawing of the window title.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a toolbar to your window in IB.  Once, you add the toolbar, you can double click on it to open the customizer view of it.  Drag a popup button into the Allowable Toolbar Items area and after it is inserted there you can drag it into the bottom area which shows the layout of the toolbar -- you can also drag out any of the default items there that you don't want.

Comment: The toolbar is not what I want. Toolbar is below the window's title. What I want is change window's title into a button with down-facing triangle that when clicked - opens menu.

Comment: You'll probably have to go with Vervious's idea then. That superview he accesses is the NSThemeView -- I don't know if there's any "danger" in that, since it's an undocumented view that Apple could change, but it should work to give you the look you want.